# Correct way of using threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing program, which is generating permutations of characters with given alphabet. I wanted to use threads. Number of threads equals number of characters in alphabet. Here's the code:

```
public class Test
{
int i=0;
char[] pass_tmp = new char[100];
void haslogen(int n, int L, int level, char[] alphabet, char[] password) 
{
    if (level == n)
    { 
        synchronized(this)
        {
            password[level]=0; 
            pass_tmp = password;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else { 
      for (int i=0;i<L;i++) {
          password[level]=alphabet[i];  
          haslogen(n,L,level+1,alphabet,password);
      }
    }
}

void crack_passwd(char[] alphabet, int dl_slowa)
{
    int L = alphabet.length;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[alphabet.length];
    for( int j=0 ; j<alphabet.length ; j++ )
    {
        final int litera = j;
        threads[j] = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                char[] password = new char[100];
                password[0]=alphabet[litera];
                haslogen(dl_slowa,L,1,alphabet,password);
            }

        });
        threads[j].start();
    }
    for( int j=0 ; j<alphabet.length ; j++ )
        try {
            threads[j].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public static void main(String[] argv)
{
    Test a = new Test();
    char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    long start, end;
    start=System.nanoTime();
    a.crack_passwd(alphabet,7);
    end=System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println(end-start+" "+a.i);
}
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong, because when I measured time of sequential generation, it was faster, really faster. Time of concurrent generation is two times longer. In my opinion, there's is something wrong with joining threads but I'm not sure. Is there any good solution for completing multiple threads if we don't know which thread is going to be finished first?

Comment: Multithreading something doesn't automatically make it faster, and adding more threads won't necessary make something that was a little faster even more fast. You have consider how many cores your CPU has - if both cores are fully utilized than your extra threads will simply wait, and if you create too many you're just adding context switching overhead. Adding more threads often gives more bang for the buck if you have many processes that become IO wait bound (such as networking or disk operations), where you want to give other tasks a chance until IO completes.

Comment: `litera`.... o kurwa!. also answer is in comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with your logic...

Just the Synchronized statement is executed 78125 times, but you have plenty of other code and loops in the "else" part.

5 Letters, targeting a length of 7 makes 5^7 = 78125 combinations.

So, assuming that your goal is to generate every possible combination in the pass_tmp value - you are exactly working sequential, because that part is never performed by two threads at the same time. (plus all the additional overhead of managed threads)

Answer (score 1):

almost all execution is under synchronized(this) and so runs sequentially. Plus execution of the synchronized statement can take a long time. Finally, the synchronized statement is executed very many times.